# Interacting with webpage to download data with R

Tags: html, r, rcurl

I posted yesterday about this issue but was mistaken about what the actual problem is.

I have a webpage that houses all of our data collected from a remote station and I periodically have to physically go onto the site to download data in a .csv format. Basically, the way the website is set up is simply a "Download" button. But when I inspect the button, it only brings back the image used for the button. I inspected the page to find that the button triggers a function, which generates a .csv. So there is no physical file behind the button. My question is if there is a way to navigate to the button and click it to generate this file and have it download through R.

I have attempted to download the data by simply clicking the download button and then going to Downloads on Chrome to find the URL associated with the file. The URL works through `download.file()` in R for a short period of time, but once new data is uploaded to the server (every 15-minutes), nothing happens. I have tried using the following code to find the `href` attribute but I get error messages.

```
realtime.page = read_html("https://stormcentral.waterlog.com/SiteDetails.php?a=263&site=2267")

realtime.page %>%
  html_nodes("a") %>%       
  html_attr("href") %>%     
  str_subset("\\.csv") %>%
  .[[1]]
```

The URL in the code is password protected, so it is difficult to provide a reproducible example. But when it runs, I get `Error in .[[1]] : subscript out of bounds`

Comment: After visiting the URL you provides using browser, it says "Site not found.", Try write a `tryCatch()` or `if` condition to detect if the button exists.

Comment: I mentioned at the bottom that it's password protected and you need account information to access the website. I apologize, I know it makes it difficult to create a reproducible example

Comment: Then I guess we can't help you much since web-scraping is very specific to the content. What you can do is print intermediate results and see where goes wrong.